# Rebol: how to apply same parse rule to multiple lines pasted from windows clipboard

Tags: parsing, rebol, text-analysis

Let's say I have in clipboard

```
title1: (todelete) blah blah
title2: (also to delete) blah blah blah
```

In the end I want this output

```
title1: blah blah
title2: blah blah blah
```

I kow how to parse one line and append it to a block

```
parse/all clipboard [
    copy x to "(" (append block x) thru ")"
    copy x to end (append block x)
]
```

But I don't know the easiest way to iterate through each line.

Comment: Please specify which Rebol version you are working with when tagging ([tag:rebol2], [tag:rebol3]) as the answers will vary.  Also, if you aren't aware of it, there is a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol) here for Rebol conversations...!

Comment: @HostileFork thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simplest way is to split the text into lines and then apply your rule to each line

```
 >> parse/all read clipboard:// "^/"
 == ["title1: (todelete) blah blah" "title2: (also to delete) blah blah blah"]
```

If you want to do it in one hit, you apply your rule more than once using `some`

```
 parse/all read clipboard:// [some [line-rule]]
```

but to account for the newline, you need to add that as an alternative as well as `end` as the alternative.

```
 parse/all read clipboard:// [some [line-rule | "^/" | end ]]
```

Comment: What terminates line-rule, in the `[some [line-rule | "^/" | end]]` case?

Comment: Well, code is untested but shouldn't the alternate "^/" terminate the first line and "end" the second?

Comment: Depends on what line-rule is.  Given the original code and its operation based on **copy to ...** you have to stop copying at some point.  Rebol does not support the construct **copy to [newline | end]** (not yet, anyway, Red does so it probably will)...but in the meantime, what's stopping the copy?